# A question about an identity in deriving Born-Infeld action

Tags: homework-and-exercises, string-theory, gauge-theory

I have a question in [David Tong's Example Sheet 4](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string/bq4.pdf)
Problem 5b, how to verify the last equation (*) on p.2? ([There is a solution for example sheet 3](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/cdab3/teaching/StringSoln3.pdf), but seems to be no solution for example sheet 4.)

> Problem 5b:
>
> Show that the equations of motion                         arising from the          Born-Infeld action are equivalent to the beta function condition for the open string,
>   $$\beta_\sigma\left(F\right)=\left( \frac{1}    {1 -F^2} \right)^{\mu \rho}\partial_\mu     F_{\rho\sigma    }=0      $$
>      **Note:** To do this, it will prove very useful if you can ﬁrst show the following results:
>   $$∂_μ\left[\operatorname{tr}      \ln(1 − F^2)\right]           = −4 ∂_\rho    F_{μ\sigma}\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma \rho   }             
> $$
>
> which requires use of the Bianchi identity for $F_{\mu \nu   }$    and
>
> $$ \tag{*}
> \begin{align}
> \partial _\mu      \left( \frac{ F}{1-F^2} \right)^{\mu\nu}
> &=
>     \left( \frac{ F}{1-F^2} \right)^{\mu\rho}   \partial_\mu F_{\rho\sigma}    \left( \frac{ F}{1-F^2} \right)^{\sigma    \nu} 
> \\ &\qquad+    \left( \frac{1}    {1 -F^2} \right)^{\mu \rho} \partial_\mu F_{\rho\sigma}\left( \frac{ 1        }{1-F^2} \right)^{\sigma    \nu}             \end{align}$$

In addition, as given in question 5a

> $$F_{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu} - \partial_{\nu} A_{\mu} $$

My attempt to prove the problem:

LHS 
$$\partial_{\mu} \left( \frac{ F}{1-F^2} \right)^{\mu\nu} = \partial_{\mu} \left[ F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \left( \frac{1}{1-F^2} \right)^{\alpha \nu} \right] = \left( \partial_{\mu}  F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\alpha \nu} + F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \partial_{\mu} \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2}  \right)^{\alpha \nu} \tag{1} $$

Using the formula in [matrix cookbook](http://orion.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) for the derivative of inverse matrix, Eq. (53)

Eq. (1) becomes
$$\left( \partial_{\mu}  F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\alpha \nu} + 2 F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \left[ \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \left( \partial_{\mu} F \right) F \frac{1}{1-F^2} \right]^{\alpha \nu} $$
$$= \left( \partial_{\mu}  F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\alpha \nu} + 2  \left( \frac{F}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\mu \rho}   \left( \partial_{\mu} F \right)_{\rho\sigma} \left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma \nu} \tag{2} $$

The second term in Eq.(2) cancels the second term in the RHS in the problem sheet equation. 
We then need to show
$$ \left( \partial_{\mu}  F^{\mu}_{\alpha} \right) \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\alpha \nu}  + \left( \frac{F}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\mu \rho}   \left( \partial_{\mu} F \right)_{\rho\sigma} \left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma \nu} -  \left( \frac{1}{1 -F^2} \right)^{\mu \rho}   \left( \partial_{\mu} F \right)_{\rho\sigma} \left(\frac{1}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma \nu} =0 \tag{3} $$

then I didn't find a way to show Eq. (3) hold. I tried to combine the second and third term, and rearrange them, but didn't got a simple expression.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): It would be good if OP (or somebody else?) could try to make the question formulation self-contained, so one doesn't have to open the link to understand the question.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS note the inclusion of a crucial omitted factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\partial_i \frac{F}{1-F^2}=-(\frac{F}{1-F^2})\partial_i (\frac{1-F^2}{F})(\frac{F}{1-F^2})$

$=-(\frac{F}{1-F^2})\partial_i(\frac{1}{F}-F)(\frac{F}{1-F^2})$

$=-(\frac{F}{1-F^2})(\partial_i(\frac{1}{F}) -\partial_iF)(\frac{F}{1-F^2})$

$=-(\frac{F}{1-F^2})(- \frac{1}{F}\partial_i F \frac{1}{F}) -\partial_iF)(\frac{F}{1-F^2})$

$=(\frac{1}{1-F^2})\partial_i F(\frac{1}{1-F^2}) + (\frac{F}{1-F^2})\partial_i F(\frac{F}{1-F^2})$

Answer (score 2):

Eq. ($\ast$) in David Tong's notes follows from the more general eq. ($\ast\ast$)

$$\tag{**}\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\lambda}{}_{\nu}
&=\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\lambda}{}_{\rho}
~\partial_{\mu}F^{\rho}{}_{\sigma}
\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma}{}_{\nu}
\\ &\qquad+\left(\frac{1}{1-F^2}\right)^{\lambda}{}_{\rho}
~\partial_{\mu} F^{\rho}{}_{\sigma}
\left(\frac{1}{1-F^2}\right)^{\sigma}{}_{\nu}  \end{align}$$

by putting the $\lambda$-index equal to the $\mu$-index, sum over $\mu$, and raise the $\nu$-index. Eq. ($\ast\ast$) is equivalent to eq. ($\ast\ast\ast$)

$$\tag{***}\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)
&=\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)
\partial_{\mu}F
\left(\frac{F}{1-F^2}\right)
\\ &\qquad+\left(\frac{1}{1-F^2}\right)
\partial_{\mu} F
\left(\frac{1}{1-F^2}\right), \end{align}$$

if we implicitly imply that every matrix $F$ carries one upper and one lower index a la $F^{\lambda}{}_{\nu}$. (Note that that there is no ambiguity in writing the matrix expression $\frac{F}{1-F^2}$ as a fraction because the numerator and the denominator commute.)

Finally, eq. ($\ast\ast\ast$)  follows by straightforward manipulations, which involve e.g. using the rule

$$\tag{****} \partial_{\mu}\frac{1}{M}~=~-\frac{1}{M}\partial_{\mu}M\frac{1}{M} $$

of how to differentiate an inverse matrix $M$. (In particular, the Bianchi identity that David Tong mentions is *not* used in the proof of eq. ($\ast\ast\ast$).)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Excuse me, I tried to use the matrix derivative in my attempt, as Eq. $(****)$   also in the matrix cookbook Eq. (53), and my Eq. (2) is not the same as (****). What is the reason for that?

Comment: It is solved in Trimok's answer, stupid me :(

Comment: Trimok's answer (v2) shows the manipulations that establishes eq. (***).